# Rearrange array elements in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an array in my batch file which looks like this:

```
"port[0] ="
"port[1] = 0"
"port[2] = 3"
"port[3] = 2"
```

Is there any nice and elegant way to move values one element back, so it'll look like this?:

```
"port[0] = 0"
"port[1] = 3"
"port[2] = 2"
"port[3] ="
```

I want something other than just `SET port[0] = %port[1]%`, etc?

Comment: don't put spaces around the equal sign...

Comment: `%port[0]%` would not exist because without a value it would be undefined. The same would also be true for `%port[3]%` after the modification.

Comment: guys thank you for pointing this out, but TBH i just showed this as an example, not the exact code =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53453204.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal  EnableDelayedExpansion
set "port[0]="   &Rem this clears/deletes the variable
set "port[1]=0"
set "port[2]=3"
set "port[3]=2"

For /L %%L in (1,1,3) do (
  set /A "New=%%L-1,Last=%%L"
  set "port[!New!]=!port[%%L]!"
)
:: finally reset the last entry
set "port[%Last%]="
set port[
```

---

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\23\SO_53453204.cmd
port[0]=0
port[1]=3
port[2]=2
```

Comment: Tracking of the last element in the loop: `Last=%%L` is redundant. The last element is predetermined.